# Extract function string before function name with regex

Tags: sed, command-line, grep, regular-expression, perl

I want a regex that would search for something like:

```
package_name.some_function_name.foo()
```

that would be part of a line and would and extract the `some_function_name`but it should be able to work also for something like:

```
if(some_function_name.foo()){
```

I.e. `package_name` is missing

I tried:

```
git grep -h foo | perl -pe 's/.*\w.*(package_name[.])?(.*_.*)[.]foo.*/$2/'
```

but does not work

If there is another way other than `perl` that is better e.g. sed I am ok with that too

Comment: Would `perl -lne 'print $1 for /(\w+)\.foo\(/g'` work for you?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: That seems to work and I am ok changing to that approach! What was I doing wrong and how come this works?

Answer (score 2):

Your `.*\w.*(package_name[.])?(.*_.*)[.]foo.*` regexp matches on lines that contain a word character and later on a `_` (I'm not even mentioning the `package_name.` since it's optional) and later on `.foo`. And captures in `$2` what would be between the last word character before the last `_` character before the last occurrence of `.foo` and that `.foo`.

For instance, in

```
asd().x_y + x.foo() + blah_x++ - _x.foobar
                           ^^^^^^^^
```

Then, the `s///` will substitute the whole line for those line that match (as the regexp matches the whole line content) but leave the other ones in untouched.

Instead, you could do:

```
perl -lne 'print for /(\w+)\.foo\(/g'
```

Which extracts the sequence of word characters before each occurrence of `.foo(` that is preceded by at least one word character.

If you want to allow that sequence of word characters to be preceded by a `something.` only if that `something` is `package_name`, you could do:

```
perl -lne '
  while (/(\w+\.)?(\w+)\.foo\(/g) {
    print $2 if !$1 || $1 eq "package_name.";
  }'
```

Or, to also exclude `other.package_name.foo()`:

```
perl -lne '
  while (/((?:\w+\.)*)(\w+)\.foo\(/g) {
    print $2 if !$1 || $1 eq "package_name.";
  }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're looking for the string before `.foo()`, you can try:

```
sed 's/^.*\W\(\w*\)\.foo().*$/\1/g'
```

###### Explanation:

- The symbol `\w` is a synonym for `[_[:alnum:]]`
- The symbol `\W` is a synonym for `[^_[:alnum:]]`

So we're looking for the part before `.foo()` that is consisted only of `alphanumeric` and `_` characters, and is preceded by `non-alphanumeric` character. We replace the entire line only with this part.

###### Caveat

If `some_function_name.foo()` appears twice at the same line, it will only catch the first instance.

If you want to ensure you catch **all** of those patterns, even if they appear twice at the same line, you can use:

```
grep -Po '\w*(?=\.foo\(\))'
```

###### Explanation:

from man grep:

> **-P**, **--perl-regexp**
>
> Interpret the pattern as a Perl-compatible regular expression
> (PCRE). This is experimental and **grep  -P** may warn of
> unimplemented features.
>
> **-o**, **--only-matching**
>
> Print  only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of a matching line,
> with each such part on a separate output line.

The part of `(?=\.foo\(\))` is called `Lookahead`, which allows you to remove part of the matching text from the pattern. So in this case, it will from `.foo()` from the pattern.